# How to pass multiple kwargs arguments in a function call in Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

I am trying to pass multiple kwargs arguments in a Python function but without any success. I am using Python 3.10.8. I have read solutions online but they're not quite working for me.

Here is the problem. I have **kwargsX**, **kwargsY** and **kwargsZ** in my function call with pre-defined **default values** and I want the user to be able to update them as they call on the function. I'd like to keep these kwargs arguments seperate for readibility purposes.

The code is as follows

```
def func(**kwargs={**kwargsX, **kwargsY, **kwargsZ}):
    init_kwargsX = {"x1":2, "x2":2}
    init_kwargsY = {"y1":-1, "y2":5}
    init_kwargsZ = {"z1":10, "z2":7}

    updated_kwargsX = init_kwargsX.update(kwargsX)
    updated_kwargsY = init_kwargsY.update(kwargsY)
    updated_kwargsZ = init_kwargsZ.update(kwargsZ)

     return updated_kwargsX.x1 + updated_kwargsZ.z2

func(**{"x1":-20, "z2":35})
```

The function should return an arbitrary addition. As you might suspect, I get **SyntaxError**. I have tried a few combinations with no luck.

Any help or pointers on this would be most appreciated.

Thanks, Caleb

Comment: It's not clear what concrete behavior you're trying to produce here.

Comment: `**kwargs={**kwargsX, **kwargsY, **kwargsZ}` is invalid syntax. What are you trying to do? Maybe just take 3 dictionaries as input? `def func(kwargsX: dict, kwargsY: dict, kwargsZ: dict):`

Comment: Aren't you just passing multiple dictionaries? Just create a single dictionary (`kwargs`) with keys (`x`, `y`, `z`) that are dictionaries them selves, and pass that. ie: `kwargs = {'x': {'key1': 'value1'},'y': {'key2': 'value2'},'z':{'key3': 'value3'}}`. Does this not result in the same behaviour?

Comment: I was trying to find an elegant way for the user to know where to place arguments for X, Y and Z, especially when there are hundreds of them. Maybe I was overcomplicating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot go that way because the language syntax just does not allow it. Full stop. The `**kwargs` syntax in a function declaration will gather all the possible keyword arguments, so it does not make sense to use it more than once.

But once you have gathered them all you can use them the way you want. Here is a possible code that should meet your requirements:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    init_kwargsX = {"x1":2, "x2":2}
    init_kwargsY = {"y1":-1, "y2":5}
    init_kwargsZ = {"z1":10, "z2":7}
    # process separately the "sub kwargs*
    for arg in init_kwargsX, init_kwargsY, init_kwargsZ:
        # search they respective keys among the passed parameters
        for key in arg.keys():
            if key in kwargs:
                arg[key] = kwargs[key]
    # done
    return init_kwargsX, init_kwargsY, init_kwargsZ
```

You can then successfully do `func(**{"x1":-20, "z2":35})` to obtain as expected:

```
({'x1': -20, 'x2': 2}, {'y1': -1, 'y2': 5}, {'z1': 10, 'z2': 35})
```

Remark: above code directly alters the `init_kwargsx` dictionaries. If you need to keep them untouched, use copies of them:

```
updated_kwargsX = init_kwargs.copy()
...
```

Comment: Thank you Serge. I used to use Scikit Learn a lot in my old job and the kwargs feature was very powerful hence me wanting to use it in my new projects. I was getting some mixed utilizations of it only and got lost in them.
Thank you for the clarification and discussion. Now I fully understand its proper usage.
Caleb